# I'm having an issue getting the yajra laravel datatables editor-tutorial to work

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, editor, yajra-datatable

I am new to Laravel and Datatables/Editor.  I used the DataTables Editor on another PHP project but am having trouble getting it to work in Laravel via the [Yajra plugin](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables-editor). I followed this tutorial https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/editor-tutorial.  Everything is compiling fine but the result is not working as I would have expected.  The 'Edit' and 'Delete' buttons are grayed out and rows are not selectable.  I suspect I'm either not including the DataTables/Editor scripts or unpacking the Editor.zip (was not in the tutorial).

[Image of what I see on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kfGV.png)

I'm using:
 - PHP Version: 7.4.2 
 - Laravel Version: 6.17.1 
 - Laravel-DataTables Editor PHP 1.9.2 (paid version-zip file renamed to Editor.zip and included
   in root folder)

**Web.php**

```
    <?php

use App\DataTables\UsersDataTablesEditor;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/users', 'UsersController@index')->name('users.index');

// from https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/editor-tutorial
Route::post('/users', 'UsersController@store')->name('users.store');

// from https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/editor-usage
Route::post('editor', function(UsersDataTablesEditor $editor) {
    return $editor->process(request());
});
```

**UserDataTableEditor.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesEditor;

class UsersDataTableEditor extends DataTablesEditor
{
    protected $model = User::class;

    /**
     * Get create action validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function createRules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:' . $this->resolveModel()->getTable(),
            'name'  => 'required',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get edit action validation rules.
     *
     * @param Model $model
     * @return array
     */
    public function editRules(Model $model)
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'sometimes|required|email|' . Rule::unique($model->getTable())->ignore($model->getKey()),
            'name'  => 'sometimes|required',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get remove action validation rules.
     *
     * @param Model $model
     * @return array
     */
    public function removeRules(Model $model)
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

**UserDataTable.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\User;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Button;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Column;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Editor;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Fields;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;


class UsersDataTable extends DataTable
{
    /**
     * Build DataTable class.
     *
     * @param mixed $query Results from query() method.
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\DataTableAbstract
     */
    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        return datatables()
            ->eloquent($query)
            ->setRowId('id') // Set the RowID
            ->addColumn('action', 'users.action');
    }

    /**
     * Get query source of dataTable.
     *
     * @param \App\User $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function query(User $model)
    {
        return $model->newQuery();
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder
     */

    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->setTableId('users-table')
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
            ->minifiedAjax()
            ->dom('Bfrtip')
            ->orderBy(1)
            ->buttons(
                Button::make('create')->editor('editor'),
                Button::make('edit')->editor('editor'),
                Button::make('remove')->editor('editor'),
                Button::make('export'),
                Button::make('print'),
                Button::make('reset'),
                Button::make('reload')
            )
            ->editor(
                Editor::make()
                    ->fields([
                        Fields\Text::make('name'),
                        Fields\Text::make('email'),
                        Fields\Password::make('password'),
                    ])
            );
    }

    /**
     * Get columns.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            Column::computed('action')
                ->exportable(false)
                ->printable(false)
                ->width(60)
                ->addClass('text-center'),
            Column::make('id'),
            Column::make('name'),
            Column::make('email'),
            Column::make('created_at'),
            Column::make('updated_at'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get filename for export.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function filename()
    {
        return 'Users_' . date('YmdHis');
    }
}
```

**UsersController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\DataTables\UsersDataTable;
use App\DataTables\UsersDataTableEditor;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function index(UsersDataTable $dataTable)
    {
        return $dataTable->render('users.index');
    }

    public function store(UsersDataTableEditor $editor)
    {
        return $editor->process(request());
    }
}
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('vendor/datatables/buttons.server-side.js') }}"></script>
    @stack('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/yajra/laravel-datatables-editor/46/552975895

**views/layouts/app.blade.php, just before < /head>**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/css/select.dataTables.min.css"/>
</head>
```

**views/layouts/app.blade.php, just before < /body>**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/js/dataTables.select.js"></script>
    @stack('scripts')
</body>
```

**app/DataTables/UsersDataTable.php**

```
return $this->builder()
                    ->setTableId('users-table')
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->minifiedAjax()
                    ->dom('Bfrtip')
// ---------------------------------------------
                    ->select(true)
//---------------------------------------------
                    ->orderBy(1)
                    ->buttons(
                        Button::make('create')->editor('editor'),
                        Button::make('edit')->editor('editor'),
                        Button::make('remove')->editor('editor'),
                        Button::make('export'),
                        Button::make('print'),
                        Button::make('reset'),
                        Button::make('reload')
                    )
                    ->editor(
                        Editor::make()
                            ->fields([
                                Fields\Text::make('name'),
                                Fields\Text::make('email'),
                                Fields\Password::make('password'),
                            ])
//---------------------------------------------
                            ->idSrc(['id'])
//---------------------------------------------
                    );
```